# NSURLConnection returns old data although NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I’ve got a serious problem. In my app I m downloading a XML-File using NSURLConnection. So far so good. But from time to time, the NSURLConnection returns an old version of the requested file although I set The cachePolicy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData.
The really disgusting part of the bug is, that the connection always return the old version of the file until I active and then deactivate the airplane mode or I rebooted the device.

An other interesting fact is: When I activate Wifi and call the app to reload the file the correct and actual version of the file is returned. But after turning off Wifi the old version is retuned again.

I m really becoming desperate with this problem and hope anybody can help me?

Here is the code from my class, downloading the file:

```
#import "HTTPReciever.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@interface HTTPReciever ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *directoryPath;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *filename;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL storeData;
@end

@implementation HTTPReciever
@synthesize receivedData = _receivedData;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize directoryPath = _directoryPath;
@synthesize filename = _filename;


- (BOOL)recieveDataFromURL:(NSURL *)url
      storeAtDirectoryPath:(NSString *)directoryPath
                  withName:(NSString *)name
{
    [self setDirectoryPath:directoryPath];
    [self setFilename:name];
    [self setStoreData:YES];
    return [self recieveDataFromURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)recieveDataFromURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                 timeoutInterval:cDefaultHTTPTimeOutInterval];

    self.receivedData = nil;
    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                          startImmediately:NO];
    if ([NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:theRequest] && connection) {
        [connection start];
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}



#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
     didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse self]]) {
        NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
        NSString *modified = [headers objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
        if (modified) {
            // not yet used
        }
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    if (self.storeData) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:self.directoryPath
                                  withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                   attributes:nil
                                                        error:nil];
        [self.receivedData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.directoryPath, self.filename]
                            atomically:YES];
    }

    [self.delegate receiver:self
       didFinishLoadingData:self.receivedData
                lastVersion:YES];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.delegate receiverFailedLoadingData:self];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
    return nil;
}


@end
```

Comment: Did you find the problem? In the enum definition for the caching options, there is a comment saying that NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData is unimplemented: `enum
{
    NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,

    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,

    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,

    NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5, // Unimplemented
};`